# What does plt refer to in this code snippet

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been looking at Conway's game of life implementation in python and came across a way to graphically represent the cells. Though, since it is my first encounter with visual aspect of python I struggle to understand what the code means overall and specifically what `plt` refers to, as it is not defined in the code. I assumed it must be an imported library, but which one?

The code:

```
size = np.array(Z.shape)
dpi = 72.0
figsize= size[1]/float(dpi),size[0]/float(dpi)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi, facecolor="white")
fig.add_axes([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], frameon=False)
plt.imshow(Z,interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.gray_r)
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/), specifically the `pyplot` module from that package.  `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` is a fairly standard way of importing it.